# Unable to syc Site Polcies from content type hub site

Tags: sharepoint-online

In Sharepoint online we are publishing site policies from contenttypehub site. When we create new Team site collection we are able to find site policies but when we create new Project site collection we are not able to find site policies. I tried to activate features like 'Content Type Syndication hub' but its not working.

Can any one help for this ?

Thanks in Advance!!!